# In a web application many jQuery+Ajax+PHP processes not running parallel in the same client

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, parallel-processing

In a web application that interacts with one server, there is a jQuery Ajax call with a PHP script that takes about 20 seconds to execute.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'createPDF.php',
        data: str,
        success: function(response) {
            showPDF(response);
        }
        error: function() {
            console.log('ERROR WHEN CREATING PDF');
        }
    });
});
```

In the meantime a user ask to the application to get a list (getList.php) through another jQuery Ajax independant from createPdf.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'getList.php',
        data: str,
        success: function(response) {
            showList(response);
        }
        error: function() {
            console.log('ERROR WHEN GETTING LIST');
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that getList.php only starts executing once createPDF.php finishes.

The application works with sessions, and tests have been done in separate clients, in which case both requests run parallel, but in the same computer they don't.

In this scenario how to run both requests parallel?

Thank you

Comment: did you try using `async :` option as true?

Comment: I tryed, but it is set by default anyways, so it made no difference

Comment: Are you SURE it's executing only after the subsequent call? By any chance, is `viewPdf()` what makes the call to getList.php? If so, that's your problem.

Comment: They are totally indepoendant processes, they only share the server, and it is happening when different clients work at the same time too, they interfer each other the same way

Comment: By any chance is it a problem caused by the VPS server stacking executions?

Comment: Can post `js` that requests `getList.php` ?

Comment: For sure, added it, as mentioned it is pretty much similar to the one of createPdf.php

Comment: How is `$.ajax()` called ?

Comment: A general outline would be (documentready > ajax(saveFile) > ajax(createPdf)) && (documentready > ajax(getList)). Only createPdf is inside another ajax, getList is independant (need getList to execute whilst createPdf does and not only after it finished)

Comment: have you tried removing all the logic from the php-script and temporarily just let the server wait for x seconds to simulate the current situation, just interested if that problem remains or if something else is wrong !?

Comment: And have you seen [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903318/multiple-ajax-requests-delay-each-other?rq=1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what is happening is that on your server the session file is locked by the first script, e.g. `saveFiles`. After that script has completed its task, the session is unlocked again. Unfortunately your script `getList` wants to access the same session, since it is locked, `getList` will have to wait until it is unlocked.

One solution for this is to call `session_write_close()` after all writing to session data has been done, that will cause the session file to be unlocked and be used by the next script. That call should obviously happen as soon as possible after `session_start()` to minimize the waiting time for other requests.

For a more detailed explanation have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6933294/2442804